# Finding E[X] based on infinitely many values of its moment generating function

Tags: pr.probability

Suppose X is a random variable. I have infinitely many values of the form $E[e^{k \alpha X}]$ for $k=0,1,2,3,...$ where $\alpha \in (0,1)$ is a constant real number. Based on these values is there any way to find $E[X]$ or a good approximation of that? Or maybe an upper bound and/or lower bound for that?